# Issue using components in Cycle.js

Tags: javascript, rxjs, cyclejs

I'm just getting started with Cycle.js, loving it so far but I'm having some issues componentizing my app.

I have this component which I want to import later from an other one:

```js
// components/header.js

function intent (DOMSource, localStorage) {
  const menuClick$ = DOMSource.select('.header .menu').events('click')

  return {
    menuClick$,
  }
}

function model (menuClick$) {
  const menuToggle = menuClick$
    .startWith(false)
    .mapTo(1)
    .fold((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
    .map(x => x % 2 === 0)

  return xs
  .combine(
    menuToggle,
  ).map(([toggle]) => ({
    toggle,
  }))
}

function view (state$) {
  return state$.map(state => (
    <header className="header" style={header}>
      <div className="menu" style={menu}>
        <div className="user" style={container}>
          <div className="image" style={image} />
          <div className="name" style={user}>Karen Serfaty</div>
          <div className="arrow" style={arrow} />
        </div>
        { state.toggle
          ? <div className="items" style={list}>
              <span id="logout">Cerrar sesión</span>
            </div>
          : <div />
        }
      </div>
    </header>
  ))
}

function Header (sources) {
  const {
    menuClick$,
  } = intent(sources.DOM)

  const state$ = model(menuClick$)
  const vtree$ = view(state$)

  return {
    DOM: vtree$,
  }
}

export default Header
```

And I want to import it here:

```js
// components/index.js

import { html } from 'snabbdom-jsx';
import xs from 'xstream'

import Header from './header'

function main (sources) {
  const header = Header(sources)

  const vtree$ = xs.of(
    <span>
      {header.DOM}
    </span>
  )

  return {
    DOM: vtree$
  }
}

export default main
```

And here is the root of the app:

```js
import {run} from '@cycle/run'
import {makeDOMDriver} from '@cycle/dom'

import main from './components'

const drivers = {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),
}

run(main, drivers)
```

If I import the `Header` component directly to the root of the app it works fine so I'm guessing there is something wrong in my `components/index.js` file?

-- Edit --

I forgot to mention that when I run the code I'm getting an `undefined` on the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `const header` is an object of streams that looks like this

`{ DOM: vTree$ }`

to make use of it, you should do something like this...

```js
// components/index.js

import { html } from 'snabbdom-jsx';
import xs from 'xstream';

import Header from './header';

function main (sources) {
  const header = Header(sources)

  const vtree$ = header.DOM.map( headerVNode => (
    <span>
      { headerVNode }
    </span>
  ));

  return {
    DOM: vtree$
  }
}

export default main;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not treating `header` as if it was a stream. After I made this change it worked:

```
function main (sources) {
  const header = Header(sources)

  const vtree$ = header.DOM
  .map(dom => <span>{dom}</span>)

  return {
    DOM: vtree$
  }
}
```

Thanks to @mciparelli for the help :)